# Subquery returns more than one row in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

The part of the code where I write,

```
(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_regular_price') price
```

It gives an error that subquery returns more than one row. How to get the price?

```
SELECT p1.ID,p1.post_title,p1.post_excerpt,p2.meta_value, p1.guid,
(select p.guid from wp_posts as p where p2.meta_value=p.ID and post_type='attachment') img, (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_regular_price') price
FROM wp_posts p1 
     JOIN wp_postmeta p2
     ON p1.ID = p2.post_id AND       
        p1.post_type = 'product' AND
        p1.post_status = 'publish' AND
         p2.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
     JOIN wp_posts p3
     ON p3.ID = p2.post_id
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: @Stender: I need this data for facebook dynamic ads.

Answer (score 0):

add CONCAT() in your subquery to group all your result with comma separate & then use FIND_IN_SET for the main query.